# How to Get data from two independent table in Spring Boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am quite new in Spring Boot and Hibernate. Here I am facing a conceptual problem. I have 3 entities like below

ModelBuyer.java

```
@Entity(name="BUYER")
public class ModelBuyer {
    @Id @GenericGenerator(name = "custom_sequence", strategy = 
            "com.test.IdGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "custom_sequence")

    @Column(name= "BUYER_ID")
    private long buyerId  ;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "COUNTRY_ID", nullable =true)
    private ModelCountry countryId  ;

    @Column(name= "BUYER_NAME")
    private String buyerName  ;
    .....
//getter setter
```

ModelCountry.java

```
@Entity(name = "BG_COUNTRY")
public class ModelCountry {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "COUNTRY_ID")
    private long countryId;

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY_NAME")
    private String countryName;

    @Column(name = "SHORT_CODE_ISO")
    private String isoCode;

   .....
   //getter setter
```

ModelPhone.java

```
@Entity(name="BG_PHONE")
public class ModelPhone {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="PHONE_ID")
    private long phoneId;

    @Column(name="OWNER_ID")
    private long ownerId;
....
//getter setter
```

Here One buyer may have multiple phone number. I want to get a list of buyer name, country, with their phone numbers. If I use `findAll()` from JpaRepository It is returning a list of buyers with country name but not with their phone numbers as it is associated. but how can I get list with phone numbers too.  My sql query will look like `"Select * from BUYER A,BG_PHONE B where A.buyerId=B.ownerId"` Here `BUYER` and `BG_PHONE` are two independent table so I can't map them as I did for `BG_COUNTRY`. So how can I do that in Spring using jpa. I have to pass the result list to thymeleaf engine.

Answer (score 0):

> Here One buyer may have multiple phone number. I want to get a list of buyer name, country, with their phone numbers.

Then you should have a OneToMany association between Buyer and Phone. And the `ownerId` should be replaced by a ManyToOne to Buyer (i.e. you would create a bidirectional association between the two entities).

Also note that your OneToOne with Country should be a ManyToOne, unless there can only be one buyer for a given country.

> Here BUYER and BG_PHONE are two independent table so I can't map them as I did for BG_COUNTRY

They're not independent, since BG_PHONE contains a column referencing the ID of BG_COUNTRY. So you can, and should create an association between the corresponding entities.

Comment: Suppose I have another enitity `USER` which may also have multiple phone number. then?

Comment: I return you the question: how would **you** design this in your database? Here's how I would do it: I would drop the "OWNER_ID" column from phone, and instead create two join tables: one between buyer and phone, and one between user and phone. And I would create two unidirectional OneToMany associations (one between buyer and phone, one between user and phone). That way, Phone would **actually** be independent of Buyer and User, and you'd still have proper associations, with foreign key constraints.